# Good HQL Editor

Tags: hibernate, ide, editor, hql

Do you know of any good HQL Editor? I've been using the hibernate tools hql editor in eclipse 
but I have a bit problem using it. Because one I've got a Generic JDBCException, all of my following queries after that will have that same error, even the queries are correct. So in order to fix that, I have to rebuild the configuration.

Any one knows if there are alternative HQL Editor out there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Besides hibernate tools , you can check out [SQuirreL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) , which is an universal GUI client for managing all the JDBC compliant database.It provides a hibernate plugin that allows generating SQL from HQL , and provides a HQL editor with the code completion and syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks @Ken Chan, at last someone answered here, I'll check on that.